# Proliferating NaN value after function execution

Tags: missing

Is there any way in Mathematica to define a NaN that proliferates after function execution without throwing errors?

Consider the following example:

```
Nearest[{1, 2, 4}, #] & /@ {1, Missing["NaN"]}
```

which generates the following output:

```
{{1}, Nearest[{1, 2, 4}, Missing["NaN"]]}
```

I would like the following:

```
{{1},{Missing["NaN"]}}
```

Best,
Max

Comment: `Unprotect[Nearest]; Nearest[a_, b_Missing] := {b}; Protect[Nearest];` ?

Comment: Not really, it is not possible.  The reason is that there is no automatic way to identify those functions for which this behaviour makes sense.  To force it for *all* functions is awfully unsafe.  If you don't force it for all, then you would need to set it up for each function you are interested in separately, similarly to what rhermans suggests.  However, I suggest using up-values (look up `TagSet`) instead of unprotecting `Nearest`.

Comment: For many other functions (not `Nearest`), `Indeterminate` already works this way.  That is the real NaN in Mathematica, not `Missing`.